# BlueJ giving no output and freezing the computer at the same time

Tags: java, bluej

I recently started java programming. I was told BlueJ is one of the best IDE's out there to start with. It worked for about a week. But then there was this one specific program, very simple program, just divided a few numbers to get an idea about associativity. It showed me an error that division by 0 is not possible. Right after that, each program i did produced no output what so ever. As in the output terminal will remain blank, completely. At the same time, my whole OS starts to slow down, even down to the file explorer. I have no idea whats causing this, since i have not changed the settings nor tampered with it.

Also i thought maybe it could be because of the complexity of the program, like a loop or something. Hence, i tried a simple hello world program, just to display a text, that's all. Even a simple program like that didn't produce an output.

What could be causing this problem ?

Operating system : Windows 10 Pro (64 bit)
RAM : 8 GB DDR3
Bluej : Version 4.1.0

Comment: BlueJ is horribly buggy, but can help teach encapsulation.

I don't understand the craze for it personally.

Comment: Is there a question here?

Comment: I'd suggest reporting it as an issue to BlueJ, http://bugs.bluej.org/secure/Dashboard.jspa

Comment: @RyanTheLeach, Even then, what do you suggest i do about this error ?

Comment: @John3136, Yes, What is the cause of this issue ?

Comment: If I knew, I would have answered.

Comment: @RyanTheLeach ok

Comment: Try uninstalling and then re-installing BlueJ.

Answer (score 0):

I would uninstall and reinstall BlueJ, as well as doing the same with Java. This is probably the best method to resolve.